# Do I have to expand $(2x+3)^4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In order to solve, $(2x+3)^4$ do I have to expand the whole thing?
So would i have to do $(2x+3)(2x+3)(2x+3)(2x+3)$ to solve?
or is there another method?

Comment: Solutions need equations... Where are yours?

Comment: sorry, i just have to simplify it

Comment: Okay, then see the answer of Rebecca for a nice shortcut. The general formula is
$$(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k y^{n-k}$$
With $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)! k!}$$
and $$j! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot \ldots \cdot j$$

Answer (score 4):

We can use the [Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).  We obtain
\begin{align*}
(2x+3)^4 &= \sum_{i=0}^4 \binom{4}{i} (2x)^i 3^{(4-i)} \\
 &= 16x^4+96x^3+216x^2+216x+81.
\end{align*}